# jQuery hidden element stays hidden when showing with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an element which has `display:none` attribute.
Now if a user hovers the parent, it will be shown:

```
.item:hover .description {
    display: block; 
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Now, when I execute

```
$(".description").hide()
```

to hide the element again (the user can click an X in the element to close it), the element will not show again if the user is hover the parent again. It stays hidden.

How do I not mess up with the css show and hide functions?

Answer (score 1):

The way you have given your code is you are mixing up CSS and JavaScript. The jQuery uses inline-styles to accomplish the `.hide()` or show. And `inline-styles` are more specific than the CSS. Either use `class`es and toggle them or just use JavaScript.

I would do this way:

```css
.item:hover .description {
  display: block; 
  z-index: 1;
}

.item .description {
  display: none;
}
```

The above is a pure CSS method. But using JavaScript, I would consider using `toggleClass()` instead of `.hide()` or `.show()`.

```css
.item:hover .description {
  display: block; 
  z-index: 1;
}

.item .description.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

And in the JS:

```css
$(".description").addClass("hidden");
```

And when you want it to be shown, you can always use:

```css
$(".description").removeClass("hidden");
```

And for toggling things, you can use:

```css
$(".description").toggleClass("hidden");
```

Comment: But he wants it to be visible initially, just not after clicking the X.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Updated something like this.

Comment: Yup, that's what I did too.

Comment: This is not gonna work when you hover over it again ;)

Comment: @Refilon My main argument here is not to mix both the JavaScript and CSS versions. Nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

It's because during hiding this element by JS, you set visibility: hidden to it. After next focus on parent, you won't set visibility: visible which is required.

You can for example execute

```
$(".description").show()
```

after next focus on parent element

Comment: Stack Snippets (`<>`) are for **runnable** examples. For just a code block, use the code block button (`{}`) (or just indent with four spaces).

Answer (score 0):

`hide` will add an inline style to hide the element, which will override the CSS style in this case.

If you're using JavaScript to hide the element, you'll need to use JavaScript to remove that inline style when no longer relevant. I'd use a `mouseleave` event handler on `.item` and a class to hide `description`:

CSS:

```
.item:hover .description.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

Hiding description in response to click on X:

```
$(".item .description").addClass("hide");
```

Removing that when the user no longer hovers `.item`:

```
$(".item").on("mouseleave", function() {
    $(this).find(".description.hide").removeClass("hide");
});
```

Either with direct handlers as above, or with event delegation (I use delegation in the example below).

**Live Example:**

```js
// Hide when X clicked
$(document.body).on("click", ".item .description .close", function() {
  $(this).closest(".description").addClass("hide");
});

// Reset when user no longer hovering
$(document.body).on("mouseleave", ".item", function() {
  $(this).find(".description.hide").removeClass("hide");
});
```

```css
.item .description {
  display: none;
}
.item:hover .description {
  display: block; 
  z-index: 1;
}
.item:hover .description.hide {
  display: none;
}

/* The following are just for the demo */
.close {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.item {
  position: relative;
  height: 2em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item .description {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #eee;
  left: 10em;
  top: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  I'm item 1
  <div class="description">
    I'm description 1
    <span class="close">[x]</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  I'm item 2
  <div class="description">
    I'm description 2
    <span class="close">[x]</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  I'm item 3
  <div class="description">
    I'm description 3
    <span class="close">[x]</span>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```